# Problem implementing a vbnet interface. Possible inheritence issue since I need to inherit from System.Drawing.Point

Tags: vb.net, interface

Apologies if this seems like a dumb question or incompetent coding. I'm very new to OOP and the visual studio 2017 environment 
and am working my way up the steep learning curve. I'm trying to write some code to handle drop and drag for a treeview.
Here's the relevant snippet:

```
Private Sub TreeView2_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TreeView2.DragOver

If e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", True) = False Then Exit Sub

Dim selectedTreeview As TreeView = CType(sender, TreeView)

Dim pt As Point 
pt = CType(sender, TreeView).PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))  '<- This Line Generates Error
Dim targetNode As TreeNode = selectedTreeView.GetNodeAt(pt)

strong textEnd Sub
```

The problem is that Point is defined as an interface which I can't correctly implement (not for a lack of trying). 
The error I receive occurs when evaluating PointToClient: **Value of Type 'Point' Can't be Converted to 'Point'.**
Here is what I have done so far regarding the interface:

```
Interface IPoint
   Sub Point(x As Integer, y As Integer)
End Interface

Class Point 
   'Inherits System.Drawing.Point      '<- Generated an error
    Implements IPoint

    Public Sub IPoint_Point(X As Integer, Y As Integer) Implements IPoint.Point
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public X, Y As Integer

    Public Sub New(newX As Integer, newY As Integer)
        X = newX
        Y = newY
    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried to inherit System.Drawing.Point to gain the necessary functionality. However this generated an error saying '**Classes can only
inherit from other classes'.**  Is there a way around this?  Does my approach make sense?

My project type in Visual Studio 2017 is Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO WorkBook.

Any guidelines and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `System.Drawing.Point` is a struct. So it can not be inherited in a class. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you think you need to define an interface or a class. You're absolutely going to have to use the `System.Drawing.Point` type at some stage so you'd have to translate anyway. What exactly do you need to achieve that that existing type doesn't/can't do for you?

Comment: I did not realize I could access Point directly as System.Drawing.Point.  I was confused because VisualStudio defined Point as an interface in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Seems to work now.  Thanks!!!